# Bing Map not rendering in New Print Layout QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, maps

I am trying to sort out a map with a Bing aerial map plugin, yet when I select New Print Layout, the aerial image will not load/render, yet all other layers do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can sort this issue out?

I am pretty new to QGIS...

Comment: What Plugin are you using?

Comment: OpenLayers Plugin

Comment: Try adding the bing layer by a different method, such as using the QuickMapServices plugin, or directly as an XYZ tile layer.

Comment: Will do! Thanks mate, I will let you know how it goes

Comment: Hey mate, I added the BING url through XYZ tiles and it now works a charm - when I render map through New Print Layout it works all sweet, so thanks heaps for the hint! For anyone else struggling open the BING aerial url in XYZ tiles (right click, 'New Connection') and here is the BING url:  http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1